# How to remove spacing at the end of the table

Tags: flutter, dart, layout

I created a custom table and for some reason the last column is getting a very large spacing / margin. I wanted the left and right margins to be the same.

````
class CustomDataTable<T> extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<T> fixedRowCells;
  final List<List<T>> rowsCells;
  final Widget Function(T data) cellBuilder;
  final double fixedColWidth;
  final double cellWidth;
  final double cellHeight;
  final double cellMargin;
  final double cellSpacing;

  CustomDataTable({
    this.fixedRowCells,
    this.rowsCells,
    this.cellBuilder,
    this.fixedColWidth = 80.0,
    this.cellHeight = 56.0,
    this.cellWidth = 200.0,
    this.cellMargin = 10.0,
    this.cellSpacing = 10.0,
  });

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => CustomDataTableState();
}

class CustomDataTableState<T> extends State<CustomDataTable<T>> {
  Widget _buildChild(double width, T data) => SizedBox(
        width: width,
        child: widget.cellBuilder?.call(data) ?? Text('$data'),
      );

  Widget _buildFixedRow() => Material(
        color: Colors.blue,
        child: DataTable(
            horizontalMargin: widget.cellMargin,
            columnSpacing: widget.cellSpacing,
            headingRowHeight: widget.cellHeight,
            dataRowHeight: widget.cellHeight,
            columns: widget.fixedRowCells
                .map((c) => DataColumn(label: _buildChild(widget.cellWidth, c)))
                .toList(),
            rows: []),
      );

  Widget _buildContentTable() => Material(
      color: Colors.grey,
      child: DataTable(
          horizontalMargin: widget.cellMargin,
          columnSpacing: widget.cellSpacing,
          headingRowHeight: widget.cellHeight,
          dataRowHeight: widget.cellHeight,
          columns: widget.rowsCells.first
              .map((c) => DataColumn(label: _buildChild(widget.cellWidth, c)))
              .toList(),
          rows: widget.rowsCells
              .sublist(widget.fixedRowCells == null ? 1 : 0)
              .map(
                (row) => DataRow(
                    cells: row
                        .map((c) => DataCell(_buildChild(widget.cellWidth, c)))
                        .toList()),
              )
              .toList()));

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        SizedBox(height: 100),
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                height: 56,
                child: _buildFixedRow(),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(child: _buildContentTable()),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}```

Table contents
````

CustomDataTable(
        rowsCells: [
          [
            'Teste teste teste teste teste teste teste teste teste teste teste teste teste teste teste teste teste',
            2312330,
            '20/07/2020'
          ],
          [
            'este teste teste teste teste teste teste teste teste teste teste teste teste teste teste teste teste',
            3234330,
            '20/07/2020'
          ],
          [
            'este teste teste teste teste teste teste teste te',
            3032454,
            '20/07/2020'
          ],
          [
            'este teste teste teste teste teste teste teste  teste teste teste te teste teste teste teste teste  teste t te teste teste teste teste teste  teste t te teste teste teste teste teste  teste t te teste teste teste teste teste  teste t te teste teste teste teste teste  teste t',
            32451,
            '20/07/2020'
          ],
        ],
        fixedRowCells: [
          "Name",
          "Number of identify",
          "birthday",
        ],
      ),

[image]